# Induction proof for stirling of first kind.

Tags: induction

I have to show that for every stirling number of the first kind $\forall n \geq 2 : s_{n,n-2} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1) $ is true.

I've started like this:

Base case: Let $n$ be $n=2$, then per defintion
$s_{n,0} = 0$.
Since we have $s_{2,2-2} = s_{2,0} = 0$ and $\frac{1}{24}2(2-1)(2-2)(3*2-1) = \frac{1}{24}2(2-1)(0)(3*2-1) = 0$ the base case is true.

Now we assume $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} $ with $ n \geq 2$
that $s_{n,n-2} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1) $ is true.

We also now, that there exists a recursive formula for the stirling numbers of the first kind which will help us for the induction.

It says that $s_{n,k} = s_{n-1,k-1}+(n-1)s_{n-1,k} $.

Now let $n \rightarrow n+1$.

$s_{n+1,n-1} = s_{n,n-2}+n*s_{n,n-1} $.

If we insert our assumption, that leaves us with

$s_{n+1,n-1} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)+n*s_{n,n-1} $.

If we insert $n=n+1$ into $\frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)$ we get
$\frac{1}{24}n+1(n)(n-1)(3n)$, so that's what we would like after the induction.

The big problem now is that I can'T get rid of $s_{n,n-1}$. I've seen a similar question for the stirling numbers of second kind which simply say that $S_{n,n-1} = $$n \choose 2$ but I don't know if this is true for the first kind and neither did I understand how we come to that conclusion. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$s_{n+1,n-1} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)+n*s_{n,n-1} \tag1$.

$s_{n,n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \tag 2$.

Substitute this in the prior equation we get

$s_{n+1,n-1} = \frac{1}{24}n(n-1)(n-2)(3n-1)+\frac{n^2(n-1)}{2} $.

which simplifies to

$s_{n+1,n-1} = \frac{1}{24}(n+1)n(n-1)(3n+2)\tag 3 $.

Thus proved by induction.  You will have to use the identity(2) to get the final proof.  I don't think there is any way out.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by identity(2)?

Comment: $s_{n,n-1} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \tag 2$..  This is what I mean.

Comment: Alright, even though I thought the final form after induction should be $\frac{1}{24}(n+1)(n)(n-1)(3n)$ cause that's what we get if we put n=n+1 into the formula that we need to proof.

Comment: It might be a stupid question. However, when doing induction last time it was always the case that you could just put n+1 into the formula you have to proof to see what the end should look like. I don't see why this is a proof if it's not the same in the end to be honest.

Comment: Wolfram states, that the special case for stirling first kind s(n,n-1) is -(n choose 2). So who's right now o_O

Comment: ${n\choose2}$ is nothing but $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$  So both are one and the same.  Expand ${n\choose2}$ to get the other expresssion.

Comment: I know, but wolfram says is $-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. Also, could you clarify why the  end of this induction isn't the same as if I would put $n->n+1$ into the statement to proof?

Answer (score 3):

Induction step:

$\begin{aligned}s\left(n+1,n-1\right) & =ns\left(n,n-1\right)+s\left(n,n-2\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{2}n^{2}\left(n-1\right)+\frac{1}{24}n\left(n-1\right)\left(n-2\right)\left(3n-1\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{24}n\left(n-1\right)\left[12n+\left(n-2\right)\left(3n-1\right)\right]\\
 & =\frac{1}{24}n\left(n-1\right)\left(n+1\right)\left(3n+2\right)\\
 & =\frac{1}{24}\left(n+1\right)n\left(n-1\right)\left(3n+2\right)
\end{aligned}
$

In the second equality we use the equality $s(n,n-1)=\frac12n(n-1)$ and also the induction hypothesis.